# Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Something>'

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I'm new to angular and firebase. I'm getting this error when I try to import `of` from `rxjs` and also when I try to return  null using  a `switchMap`.
**auth.service.ts**

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { Observable,  of } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppUser } from './models/app-user'
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,  
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.user$=afAuth.authState;
  }

  login(){
    let returnUrl=this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl')||'/'
    localStorage.setItem('returnUrl',returnUrl)
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
  }
  logout(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut()
  }

  get appUser$():Observable<AppUser>{
    return this.user$
    .pipe(switchMap(user=> {
      if(user) return this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges();
    return Observable.of(null);    <==line of error
    })
}
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AppUser } from './models/app-user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) { }

  save(user: firebase.User){
    this.db.object('/users/'+user.uid).update({
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email
    })
  }

  get(uid: string):AngularFireObject<AppUser>{
    return this.db.object('/users/'+uid)
  }
}
```

**app.user.ts**

```
export interface AppUser{
    name: string,
    email:string,
    isAdmin: boolean
}
```

Getting `Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<AppUser>'` as error.

Comment: can you try to just `return empty()` instead of `return Observable.of()`?

Comment: It worked for ```return of(null)```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [typescript optional parameters](https://medium.com/@kgrvr/typescript-functions-optional-parameters-b245e7a06d7d)

instead of `name: string;`

change to `name?: string;`

```
export class AppUser {
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
  isAdmin?: boolean;
  photoURL?: string;
}
```

Hopefully that works.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your might have enabled `strictNullChecks` in your `tsconfig.json` so it won't let you assign `null` to type `AppUser` which is correct.

So you can define the return type as `Observable<AppUser | null>` which includes also `null` values.

Maybe also try upgrading RxJS to the latest version possible for you. I think there used to be a problem with `of`s typings https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4723 but maybe that's unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the responses. It worked by adding `isAdmin?: string` to `app-user.ts` and also `import { of } from 'rxjs'
...
return of(null)`
worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and all I did was adding `import { of } from 'rxjs'`